# Swift 3 - Conditional expanded table view cell height

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am using Swift 3.  I have expandable table view cells but is it possible to get a different row height depending on which cell was clicked?  For example, if the first cell is clicked, I want it to return 420 for height and if other cells are clicked, I want it to return 300 for height.

Here is my cell class.

```
class ResultsCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var introPara : UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var section_heading : UILabel!

    class var expandedHeight : CGFloat = { get { return 420.0 } }
    class var defaultHeight : CGFloat { get { return 44.0 } }

    var frameAdded = false

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        section_heading.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    }

    func checkHeight() {
        introPara.isHidden = (frame.size.height < ResultsCell.expandedHeight)
    }

    func watchFrameChanges() {
        if(!frameAdded) {
            addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame", options: .new, context: nil)
            checkHeight()
        }
    }

    func ignoreFrameChanges() {
        if(frameAdded){
            removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")
        }
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit called");
        ignoreFrameChanges()
    }

    // when our frame changes, check if the frame height is appropriate and make it smaller or bigger depending
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "frame" {
            checkHeight()
        }
    }

}
```

What I have tried is something like this.

```
var _expandedHeight : CGFloat = 420.0
class var expandedHeight : CGFloat { get { return _expandedHeight } set (newHeight) { _expandedHeight = newHeight } }
var isRow0 = false

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    section_heading.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if isRow0 {
        ResultsCell.expandedHeight = 300.0
    }
    else {
        ResultsCell.expandedHeight = 420.0
    }
}
```

And then in the `TableViewController`...

```
// return the actual view for the cell
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let resultcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "resultCellTemplate", for: indexPath) as! ResultsCell

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        resultcell.isRow0 = true
    } else {
        resultcell.isRow0 = false
    }

    return resultcell
}
```

But I'm getting errors on the getter/setter line: `instance member _expandedHeight cannot be used on type ResultsCell`

How can I achieve the behavior that I want?

Answer (score 0):

Use tableview update methods to reevaluate each cell's height

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Changes to the tableview cells' heights will automatically be calculated with `heightForRowAtIndexPath`
try setting your height w.r.t indexpath
make user you mention the heightForRowAtIndexPath to calculate the right height.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in the `delegate` of your TableView.

Your TableView has a `delegate` private instance variable, whose value should implement protocol `UITableViewDelegate`. This protocol contains many functions which the `UITableView` calls in order to set its own appearance.

For more info:

The `UITableViewDelegate` protocol:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate

The `UITableView` `delegate` instance variable: 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview#delegate

What you want to do is to implement the `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` method on your `UITableViewDelegate` object. This method gets two parameters: The first is the `UITableView` itself, and the second is the `IndexPath` of the row being prepared for rendering. An `IndexPath` is an object which has `section` and `row` properties corresponding to the cell being rendered.

What you want to do is have some way of computing whether a cell is expanded or not based on its `IndexPath`.

Swift `IndexPath` reference: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexpath

Trying to do this based on the `UITableViewCell` itself is an incorrect approach, as you usually should not analyze the cell before it is rendered.

A way to do this would be to have your `UITableView`-inheriting class keep a (possibly nested) array of booleans indicating which cells should be expanded or not. Then you could use the `IndexPath`'s `row` and possibly `section` as indices into this array in order to determine whether the cell is expanded or not. Something like this:

```
class MyTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDelegate {
  /* ... */

  private var expanded: [Bool] = []

  init() {
    super.init()
    self.delegate = self
  }

  func setData(data: [SomeType]) {
    //set the data for the table here
    expanded = [Bool](repeating: false, count: data.count)
  }

  /* ...logic to expand  and collapse cells... */

  func tableView(_ view: UITableView, 
                 heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if expanded[indexPath.row] {
      return expandedHeight
    } else {
      return collapsedHeight
    }
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

The proper way to set your data would be to call a method on your `UITableViewDataSource`, but I'm assuming you'd set data on the TableView itself for the sake of simplicity.

Don't try to set the `UITableView`'s properties by hand. The `delegate` and `dataSource`-based workflow of `UITableView`s is set up so that your table view works efficiently and only updates itself when it needs to.